# Confirm the Ending

Tags: javascript

I was trying to write a function to check if "str" ends with the given "target". I eventually got the right answer but was wondering what I did wrong with the code I wrote below.

```
function confirmEnding(str, target) {
  var targetArray = target.split("");
  var strArray = str.split("");
  var ending = [];
  for (i=target.length; i>0; i--){
    if (strArray[str.length-i]==targetArray[target.length-i]){
      ending.push(targetArray[target.length-i]);
    } else {
      ending.push(0);
    }
  }
  return ending==targetArray;
}
```

Basically so if the first letters of both str and target are the same, I added it to an array called "ending" and otherwise, added 0. Then once it's done, I would compare the two arrays and it would give me true if str does end with target and false otherwise. It only returned false and I want some insight into this. Could you give me some feedback on this? Thank you.

Comment: `==` is reference equality when used with two arrays; it doesn’t compare their contents. `[1] != [1]`. (You also don’t need to convert the strings to arrays to do this; strings’ characters can already be accessed by index with bracket notation. Also also, `str.endsWith(target)`)

Comment: Your comment was really helpful! Thank you so much :) We were specifically asked not to use the method actually haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `ending` and `targetArray` are two different arrays, even if the contents are same, `ending==targetArray;` will not give `true` with '==' operator.

To check the equality of contents of arrays yo will have to iterate over each content and check the equality or if you are particular about '==' you an use

```
ending.toString() == targetArray.toString()
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) It makes a lot more sense now